# POSTFIX- BODY_CHECK - Regular expression not working

Tags: regex, postfix-mta

/etc/postfix/smtp_body_checks

**/(?!X-PPP-Vhost: test.com)(?!.|\n|\r)*(\btest.com\b)/   REJECT SPAM EMAIL**

Basically email body will have domain at end if its valid email send my users not some spam send by system that is hacked.

**postmap -q - regexp:/etc/postfix/smtp_body_checks  < myfilters/data.txt**

data.txt contain email data ( whole email)

Error is

**postmap: warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/smtp_body_checks, line 1: Invalid preceding regular expression**

It do not like question mark. when i remove it basically ignore match. if i use
**/(\btest.com\b)/**   it matches all test.com string and spits out that REJECT SPAM EMAIL string.

But i checked that in this website , it found match. No error. Stuck here now. who can help.

https://regex101.com

Any expert?

I want to check only body. Body start after HOST info. There is no other marker for body except that. Want to ignore those matches and only match last test.com in body

**email sample text**

> Blockquote

From: alex@test.comTo: alex2 alex2@test.comSubject: testing email filterUser-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.4.11
Message-ID: 3907e0dede914479d42ecddb829da9a6@test.comX-Sender: alex@test.comContent-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII;
format=flowedContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bitX-PPP-Message-ID:
164243412854.574642.9867894171662743646@intelligent-mahavira.ip.plesk.pageX-PPP-Vhost: test.com

hi
response
Thanks
alex
**test.com**

> Blockquote

Match that last test.com

I want to reiterate the issue again. It works in regex101.com not in linux pcre command.

new multiline regex that works in regex101.com
(?s:.*\s)\Ktest.com(?!.*X-PPP-Vhost: test.com)

Why linux complaining this

**postmap: warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/smtp_body_checks, line 1: Invalid preceding regular expression**

ok changed from regexp to pcre to escape that error

sudo apt install postfix-pcre

postmap -q - pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_body_checks  < myfilters/data.txt

but pcre ignores last test.com. craps

BIG CRAPS.
Body check read line by line only. No use.

Next is i prepend domain name to Subject line. if its not found it will reject that email

It seems like BODYCHECK is useless. No reject.

Comment: edit the question to include the `data.txt` email and what you are trying to match in it.

Comment: data.txt is sample text attached.  Idea is if there is a signature token pass the email. if its missing then reject. If anyone hacked and sending email with host domain email and they probably wont have signature and will be rejected.

Comment: from http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html "CONFIGURATION PARAMETERS
       body_checks
              Lookup  tables with content filter rules for message body lines.
              These filters see one physical line at a time, in chunks  of  at
              most $line_length_limit bytes."

Sounds like the checks will (a) only see the message body lines and (b) will be applied one line at a time.  you are probably not able to test against headers in smtp_body_checks and you may not be able to use multi-line regexp

Comment: Its body check. regexp has error (dont like ?) . pcre not seeing last text.
smtp_body_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_body_checks but i am not running postfix yet. first i have to ensure regex work with postmap. so far fail. i can run content filter but i dont want to use separate sendmail

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
/(X-PPP-Vhost: test.com)/m REJECT
```

or if you want to inverse this

```
!/(X-PPP-Vhost: test.com)/m REJECT
```

https://regex101.com/r/WmonHf/1

the regex is matching the domain after X-PPP-Vhost
the `/m` makes it match across multiple lines

Comment: I need to match only last test.com.  End word ( signature). It should not match test..com near host. once i match then i inverse it so if there is no test.com as signature reject.

Comment: you will have to be clearer with the problem - the regex matches `X-PPP-Vhost: test.com` which is at the end of the message.  It would not match `alex@test.com` for example

Comment: you can add some additional examples of emails that should matxh and some that should not to clarify

Comment: (?s:.*\s)\Ktest.com(?!.*X-PPP-Vhost: test.com)
This one works in regex 101 site but not in that posfix command. same issue